# EditText Style is not applying

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have used a custom style for the app and I am using 'TextInputLayout' Widget but when I am trying to change the font of edittext it's not being applied. Though When I am not using 'TextInputLatout' Widget, fonts are working fine.

```
 <resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/RobotoEditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>


<style name="MyCustomToolBarTheme"                    parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFF</item>
</style>



<style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>

</style>


<style name="RobotoEditTextStyle" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>



<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"    parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"     />





<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
      </style>

</resources>
```

Here is the code Inside Activity

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">


<include layout="@layout/app_bar"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    >





    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/error_et_login_email"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >


        <EditText
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:id="@+id/et_login_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/error_et_login_password"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >



        <com.github.itwenty.passwordedittext.PasswordEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_login_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:passwordPeek="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_login_create_account"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Create Account?"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_login_forgot_password"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Forgot Password?"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login_login"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:background="#000"
        />


</LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do that programmatically, in your class, including your font in assets folder and with something like:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "your_font.ttf");
TextInputLayout yourtextil= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourTextInputLayoutId);
yourtextil.getEditText().setTypeface(tf);
```